# Responsive Sidebar Using Divi Theme in WordPress

Tags: android, css, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

I am trying to hide the sidebar for mobile devices in my WordPress site with the Divi theme. I have tried to use media queries to do this but it hasn't worked.

My media query:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .menu-decoglobofx-container {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the plugin [Hide Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-widgets/) and the sidebar still displays when I test the page on my mobile device [try it yourself and see](http://masqueglobos.com/bodas/). Does anyone know how to get this to work properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do good .. just use it with proper page_id

```
   @media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .et_pb_sidebar_0 {
    display:none !important;}
    }
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do this @hector-de-prada. If you want to have a collapsing sidebar for mobile, you need to use JS. Here is a Codepen example of how this works using media queries and jQuery `toggleClass`: http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/dGOMYO

Answer (score 1):

Change this in css:

```
   @media (max-width: 479px)
.et_pb_section .et_pb_row .et_pb_column.et_pb_column_1_4 {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;

}
```

with:

```
 @media (max-width: 479px)
.et_pb_section .et_pb_row .et_pb_column.et_pb_column_1_4 {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: I have tried but it is still showing. I have also added a class to the divi section called .barrita and I have added this code but nothing looks to work 
 @media (max-width: 479px)
.barrita {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    display:none;

}

Comment: Did you added this at `.et_pb_section .et_pb_row .et_pb_column.et_pb_column_1_4 ` class?

Comment: Yes, I copied the media query you just gave me into the style.css of my child theme